# what is the meaning of "skip login protect" in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

what is the meaning of `skip the login protect` in asp.net, 
and the difference between `server.Transfer()` and `Response.Redirect()`?

My mind:

1. the meaning like that i can write some queryString on the URL direct and this request can be solve.isn't it?
2. the difference between `server.Transfer()` and `Response.Redirect()` is that `response.Redirect()` redirecta to another page and the URL will be changed, however `Server.Transfer()` cannot change the URL.

Is this right?

Comment: See the documentation - especially since you know the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per MSDN:

[**HttpServerUtility.Transfer Method (String)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k58xk7.aspx) - For the current request, terminates execution of the current page and starts execution of a new page by using the specified URL path of the page.

[**HttpResponse.Redirect Method (String, Boolean)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx) - Redirects a client to a new URL. Specifies the new URL and whether execution of the current page should terminate.

**To Elaborate**

Response.Redirect sends a 302 HTTP status code to the browser, which tells the browser to go to the new URL.

Server.Transfer will shunt the processed request of another .aspx page to the current request, leaving the URL unchanged, an operation that happens entirely on the server.

Comment: After the <b>Transfer Method</b> ,it will go back the page which include this method and the result will transmit the page ?

Comment: No, it will only send the output of the transferred page to the current request. The output of the first page will be discarded. Per MSDN "terminates execution of the current page".

Comment: But I did it like that:I created tow pages,one is named "button.aspx" with a button in it,the other is named "index.aspx" which include "button.aspx" by Server.Transfer().run it : "index.aspx" show a button   which is in "button.aspx" . I click this button and it response me that the URL changed and turn "button.aspx".

Comment: You are seeing the URL change when clicking the button because the "button.aspx" page is posting back to itself, not to "index.aspx". The only way to change that behavior is to rewrite the form tag so it posts back to somewhere else. Of course, you could also change your button to a hyperlink that takes you to where you want to go directly (from the browser). It is very unclear what you wish to achieve.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to use a custom URL for a page, you can use .NET routing or URL rewriting. .NET routing is the better of the two.